# DNN Upgrading and mobile redirect

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

Couple questions here:

1. Is there a difference in "skin" rendering for DNN between 5.0 and 7.0 where if a site was upgraded the skin would be rendered incorrectly?
2. If skins are version specific, is there a way in DNN 5.0 to have a universal C# event that on every page load if the browser is mobile render the site with the mobile "skin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Simple answer, yes. Longer answer, it depends on how the skin was developed in DNN5, There are most likely minor changes in the skin.CSS file that might be necessary. How many changes will vary based on the skin though, so it is hard to estimate how much work will be necessary
2. Sure, but you would have to do quite a bit of custom development to do that. I would recommend looking at DNN7 for the mobile redirection capabilities.